# How to run windows script file for taking project from TFS?

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file, tfs, ionic-framework

I am developing ionic application and using gulp utility to minify js files.
To avoid gulp getting configured in all the systems of team members, I am planning to have remote system which will communicate with TFS, take the project and put it in some folder and then I will install gulp on that and run task accordingly.
But my question is how to make connection from remote system to TFS to get project ? I know through Eclipse i can pull and get the project but is there any independent approach like running batch file and getting things done.
Overall aim is to avoid installing run in all the team member system instead they can connect to remote system and take the minified versions.
Help is appreciated !

Comment: So you're saying that the remote server should automate minification ? And by remote server, do you mean Git or deployment server?

Comment: @PrashantGhimire Its remote system where my gulp will be installed .. I will take pull of my latest project from TFS and then run gulp to minify the project files in my remote system .. and then finally my team members can access the system and get the minified version .. But how to write file which will communicate my TFS and get the project ?

Comment: In that case, why don't you commit the minified file beforehand ?

Comment: @PrashantGhimire then I expect gulp to be installed on eacj=h and every system ... with necessary plugins .. and I want to avoid that .. so

Comment: I'm aware that you can automate minification in deployment using https://www.npmjs.com/package/flightplan .If it's your own server, you should be able to do it. Idk if that help you.

Comment: Oh well, then flightplan has to be installed everywhere ... :\ ... Lol

Comment: @PrashantGhimire why flightplan ? not possible through bat file / command prompt directly ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you just want to get a version from TFS to the workspace on your remote machine.

There are several ways to achieve this:

1. Install VS/Team Explorer on the remote machine, then perform get latest or get specific version from history.
2. Go to TFS web portal, navigate to **CODE** tab, select the project, and choose **Download as Zip**.
3. Use TFS [Get command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx) to get (download) either the latest version or a specified version of one or more files or folders from Team Foundation Server to the workspace.

Syntax:

```
tf get [itemspec] [/version:versionspec] [/all] [/overwrite] [/force] [/remap]
[/recursive] [/preview] [/noautoresolve] [/noprompt]
[/login:username,[password]]
```

4. Write a batch script to invoke command line. Check http://n3wjack.net/2014/02/02/how-to-pull-from-tfs-from-the-command-line/